# How to replicate custom aggregation of data from R into python?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

I have below example lines of codes in R. I want to achieve the same output using python. I don't know if it can be doable using pivot_table() and groupby.

```
    df1 <- df %>% 
      group_by(A,B,C,D,E,F) %>% 
      summarise(v1 = (v1/7)*6,
                v2 = (v2/7)*6,
                v3 = mean(v3)
                ) %>% 
      data.frame()
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Data is huge sharing sampled rows. Code has to be exactly replicated even though v3 seems as is appearing in the output.
Sample Data (df)-->

```
A         B     C      D          E      F  G    H   v1       v2     v3
1177    382861  CF  code_name   Place1  abc N   MK1  18892    93    18892
1177    382863  CF  code_name   Place2  abc W   MK2  10670.5  70    10670.5
1177    382865  CF  code_name   Place3  abc S   MK3  5675     56    5675
1177    382866  CF  code_name   Place2  abc S   MK2a 7428.26  49    7428.26
1177    382868  CF  code_name   Place2  abc W   MK2b 4458.8   28    4458.8
1177    382869  CF  code_name   Place2  def W   MK2c 0        0     0
1177    382873  CF  code_name   Place4  def W   MK4  14112    96    14112
1177    382875  CF  code_name   Place5  def N   MK5  11807    70    11807
1178    382861  CF  code_name   Place1  abc N   MK1  345      11    1587
1178    382863  CF  code_name   Place2  abc W   MK2  922      51    23054
```

Expected output -->

```
 A         B    C       D         E      v1         v2          v3
1177    382861  CF  code_name   Place1  16193.1429  79.714286   18892
1177    382863  CF  code_name   Place2  9146.1429   60          10670.5
1177    382865  CF  code_name   Place3  4864.2857   48          5675
1177    382866  CF  code_name   Place2  6367.08     42          7428.26
1177    382868  CF  code_name   Place2  3821.8286   24          4458.8
1177    382869  CF  code_name   Place2  0           0           0
1177    382873  CF  code_name   Place4  12096       82.285714   14112
1177    382875  CF  code_name   Place5  10120.2857  60          11807
1178    382861  CF  code_name   Place1  295.7143    9.428571    1587
1178    382863  CF  code_name   Place2  790.2857    43.714286   23054
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expcted ouput?

Comment: There is no aggreagation, only divide `7` and multiple `6` ? So not groupby necessary?

Comment: adding sample data removes guess work and makes it easy for the community to profer tailored solutions

Comment: I think you want something like `df.groupby(['A','B','C','D','E','F'])[['v1', 'v2', 'v3']].apply(lambda g: g/7*6)`, but as said above, this does not require grouping as the operation is group independent

Comment: @jezrael  Edited the question with sample data and expected output with a slight change in question.

Comment: @PrasadPatil - Working like you need?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#processing per groups not necessary (slowier in groupby, same ouput)
df[['v1','v2']] =  df[['v1','v2']] / 7 * 6

#new column filled by means per groups
df['v3'] = df.groupby(['A','B','C','D','E','F'])['v3'].transform('mean')

print (df)
      A       B   C          D       E    F  G     H            v1         v2  \
0  1177  382861  CF  code_name  Place1  abc  N   MK1  16193.142857  79.714286   
1  1177  382863  CF  code_name  Place2  abc  W   MK2   9146.142857  60.000000   
2  1177  382865  CF  code_name  Place3  abc  S   MK3   4864.285714  48.000000   
3  1177  382866  CF  code_name  Place2  abc  S  MK2a   6367.080000  42.000000   
4  1177  382868  CF  code_name  Place2  abc  W  MK2b   3821.828571  24.000000   
5  1177  382869  CF  code_name  Place2  def  W  MK2c      0.000000   0.000000   
6  1177  382873  CF  code_name  Place4  def  W   MK4  12096.000000  82.285714   
7  1177  382875  CF  code_name  Place5  def  N   MK5  10120.285714  60.000000   
8  1178  382861  CF  code_name  Place1  abc  N   MK1    295.714286   9.428571   
9  1178  382863  CF  code_name  Place2  abc  W   MK2    790.285714  43.714286   

         v3  
0  18892.00  
1  10670.50  
2   5675.00  
3   7428.26  
4   4458.80  
5      0.00  
6  14112.00  
7  11807.00  
8   1587.00  
9  23054.00
```

If need custom function:

```
def f(x):
    x['v1'] = x['v1'] / 7 * 6
    x['v2'] = x['v2'] / 7 * 6
    x['v3'] = x['v3'].mean()
    return x

df = df.groupby(['A','B','C','D','E','F']).apply(f)

print (df)
      A       B   C          D       E    F  G     H            v1         v2  \
0  1177  382861  CF  code_name  Place1  abc  N   MK1  16193.142857  79.714286   
1  1177  382863  CF  code_name  Place2  abc  W   MK2   9146.142857  60.000000   
2  1177  382865  CF  code_name  Place3  abc  S   MK3   4864.285714  48.000000   
3  1177  382866  CF  code_name  Place2  abc  S  MK2a   6367.080000  42.000000   
4  1177  382868  CF  code_name  Place2  abc  W  MK2b   3821.828571  24.000000   
5  1177  382869  CF  code_name  Place2  def  W  MK2c      0.000000   0.000000   
6  1177  382873  CF  code_name  Place4  def  W   MK4  12096.000000  82.285714   
7  1177  382875  CF  code_name  Place5  def  N   MK5  10120.285714  60.000000   
8  1178  382861  CF  code_name  Place1  abc  N   MK1    295.714286   9.428571   
9  1178  382863  CF  code_name  Place2  abc  W   MK2    790.285714  43.714286   

         v3  
0  18892.00  
1  10670.50  
2   5675.00  
3   7428.26  
4   4458.80  
5      0.00  
6  14112.00  
7  11807.00  
8   1587.00  
9  23054.00
```